# border-right don't work in Firefox browser

Tags: css, firefox, datatables

```
#content table.datatable th {
border:1px solid #000;  
border-right:1px solid black;    
border-color:black;
}
```

border-right dont work for th-table header elements in Firefox browser. Any suggestions please.

Comment: `border-right:1px solid black !important;  ` and you are using black already so your won't see it

Comment: [Using !important in your CSS usually means you're narcissistic & selfish or lazy. Respect the devs to come...](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: It's hard to say why this doesn't work. Maybe the selector doesn't match the th, or there is another matching selector of equal weight further down your css, or a more specific one...  You can `inspect element` in your browser and see which CSS rules are applied to it. I know in Chrome you can see all rules, including the rules (stricken out) that are overruled by others. FireFox probably also has [features like that](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: have yoy jsfiddle or url of your page?

Answer (score 0):

the css is working just fine. You might want to change the colors, just to be able to see the changes

```
#content table.datatable th {
  border:1px solid #000;  
  border-right:1px solid red;    
  /*border-color:black;*/
}
```

---

If you still do not see any change, you might be having wrong markup. It should look something like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <table class="datatable">
        <tr>
            <th>Heading 1</th>
            <th>Heading 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

*Note*: The contents of div, table, th, td are dummy and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet you give you've set the border colour to be black 3 times over. If in your live code you have a different colour (say blue, for example) in the second line, then your first statement will set the colour for the whole border to be black (#000), then the second one will set the right border only to be blue. So far so good. But then your third line `border-color:black` sets the whole border to be black again, thus overriding the second line.

If you have two conflicting property settings like this in the same CSS rule, then the later one will overrule the earlier one. (This is just the same as the more usual situation where a rule later in the stylesheet will override one earlier in that stylesheet, or in an earlier stylesheet, given two rules with the same specificity.)

Putting it another way, the fact that one setting is for border and another is for border-right doesn't change anything; the border property is just a composite way of setting the four properties of the left, right, top and bottom borders all in one go. It's the order these settings appear in that matters,  not whether you are specifying the four-in-one border or a single side only.